# Is it possible to calculate the integral $\int_{0} ^{1} \int_{0} ^{3} \int_{4y} ^{12} \frac{5 \cos{x^{2}}}{4 \sqrt{z}} dx dy dz$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to compute the triple integral $\int_{0} ^{1} \int_{0} ^{3} \int_{4y} ^{12} \frac{5\cos{x^{2}}}{4 \sqrt{z}} dx dy dz.$ I've tried every single method I know (by substitution, by parts and changing coordinates), but I'm unable of calculating it. I'd like to know if it is possible to calculate it and, in case it is, a small hint so I can solve it myself.

Comment: As your respondants have noted, $\int \cos(x^{2})\, dx$ is not an [elementary integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function). But if you change the order of integration as example says, the resulting integral _can_ be evaluated exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change order of first and second integrals ($dx dy \to dy dx)$ which might be tricky, but you can do it if you sketch your domain. I might add some sort of sketch later, but for now I'll just put it here without proof.
\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \int_0^3 \int_0^{4y} \frac {5\cos x^2}{4\sqrt z} dx dy dz &= \int_0^1 \int_0^{12} \int_0^{\frac 14x} \frac {5\cos x^2}{4\sqrt z} dy dx dz = \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{12} \frac {5\cos x^2}{16\sqrt z} xdx dz = \int_0^1 \int_0^{12}\frac {5 \cos x^2}{32\sqrt z} d(x^2) dz = \\
&= \int_0^1 \left .\left( \frac {5\sin x^2}{32\sqrt z} \right ) \right |_0^{144}dz = \int_0^1 \frac {5\sin 144}{32 \sqrt z} dz = \\
&= \left . \left (\frac {5\sin 144}{16} \sqrt z \right ) \right |_0^1 = \frac {5\sin 144}{16}
\end{align}

### Note

By some reason WA doesn't calculate it, so here's the results from Mathematica

[image: result]